# Js array doesnt return all elements in array,rather displays undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-video

I have a script that takes videos in an array and assigns them to an html5 video element source attribute to play the videos.I also have next and previous buttons to move to the next video or backwards.Each set of videos that belong to a particular array varies from 1 to 20 videos.

I'm encountering this problem,not all the videos will play,and wherever it stops,I get an "undefined" error,to elaborate on this,I can have a set of 15 videos,the first 10 will play just fine with me clicking the next button and when i try going next to the 11th video,it doesn't load and i get that error. What could be causing this?

I tried logging the array length to the console to see if its actually right and it displays exactly the amount of videos in the array but for some reason doesn't play all of them.Here is the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //setting up next and previous video buttons.
  var player = document.querySelector('#myvideo');
  var i = 0;
  var back = document.querySelector('#previousBtn');
  var next = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');
  var videos = [  // here is your list of videos in that particular course based on scan server directory query
  <?php 
 echo "'" . implode("','", $videosarray) . "'";
   ?>   
 ];

  if (i >= videos.length) {
    i = 0;
  }

  console.log(videos.length); //length of the videos array.

  back.addEventListener('click', function() {
    player.src = "<?php echo '../' . $result['videopath'];?>" + videos[i == 0 ? videos.length-- : i--];
    myvideo.play();
  }, false);

  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    player.src = "<?php echo '../' . $result['videopath'];?>" + videos[i == videos.length-- ? 0 : i++];
    myvideo.play();
  }, false);

  player.src = "<?php echo '../' . $result['videopath'];?>" + videos[i]; //src attribute of the first video
  player.play(); //init the video player
</script>
```

Comment: Please spend some time on formatting your question in a more readable way. A wall of text isn't fun to read nor does it help to understand the question.

Comment: Try logging the whole array to console and make sure all the values are correct

Comment: @Mahan_F I tried that as well and the array logs perfectly on the console.I can even see the whole set of array elements when i right click and view source.

Comment: @John Alright then,do you think you can delete all the PHP stuff and replace them with hardcoded values for the array and the video path. That way you can add some HTML and modify your question to be a code snippet which we can run. It will make it easier to be able to run the code

Comment: For cases like `videos = /* php stuff to get a collection into something that JS understands */` use `json_encode()` instead of a DIY solution